# GeoBook 140 - No Sound

Tags: sound

Does anyone got a Geo Notebook and fixed the Sound issue? I tried everything i found.

Specs:

0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
GEO-GeoBook140-Defaultstring-IG218
1 [camera         ]: USB-Audio - USB camera
SunplusIT Inc USB camera at usb-0000:00:15.0-6, high speed

00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)

Answer (score 0):

The sound on my Geobook 120 doesn't seem to work either. The only way I could get the sound working was through bluetooth.